# Read/Modify response of MVC Action with filters

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have an HttpPost action as below:

```
[HttpPost]
public string GetPerson()
{
    string output = GetPerson();
    return output;
}
```

I am returning xml as a string. Is it possible read this string in actionfilter OnResultExecuted or OnResultExecuting methods?

Comment: Yes You will have to create a new attribute. What are you trying to achieve ?

Comment: @Mads... thx for your helps. I want to log all incoming and outgoing. I can catch the requests but not could not read the responses.

Comment: @OmerK I've updated my answer to include a sample.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On each of these actionfilters you can get the result (an `ActionResult` object).

For `OnResultExecuted` you can get it from the `ResultExecutedContext.Result` property

I've added a sample below.

```
public class InterceptValueAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{


    public override void OnResultExecuted(ResultExecutedContext filterContext)
    {

        var result = filterContext.Result as ContentResult;

        var data = result.Content;

      //use data as required

    }

}
```

You can use it on your action as below.

```
[HttpPost]
[InterceptValue]
public string GetPerson()
{
    string output = GetPerson();
    return output;
}
```

Comment: thx, this is what i was looking for. But if my action returns view, is above works again?

Comment: @OmerK Not really ... this works when you action returns a string (thats why i used a content result) for a View you can still log whatever you want from the ActionResult data.

Comment: @OmerK Instead of `result.Content` you can say `result.ToString()` if you are expecting an ActionResult instead of a ContentResult.

Comment: @OmerK - you could use `if (filterContext.Result is ContentResult) { ... } else if (filterContext.Result. is ActionResult) { ... }` and take the appropriate action depending on what type of result you have.